# Use the DataTemplate to display the content in the exact same way as not using a DataTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox

My ListBox currently binds as expected using

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ChildDuplicate, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" DataContext="{Binding}"  Height="Auto" >
```

Where ChildDuplicate is an `ObservableCollection<MyUserControl>`

The problem I am facing is I need to add a button for every item within the ListBox (so it shows both my MyUserControl and the Button control).

This button cannot live within the MyUserControl for several reasons.

I was hoping to use a DataTemplate but this doesn't seem to work (XmlParser error is thrown), I've tried

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ChildDuplicate, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" DataContext="{Binding}"  Height="Auto" >
    <ListBoxItem>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ContentControl Content="{Binding}"></ContentControl>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBoxItem>
</ListBox>
```

I also tried using the ItemsControl control in the same way, the same issue.

Any idea how I use the DataTemplate to display the content in the exactly same way as not using a DataTemplate?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
<ListBoxItem>
  <ListBoxItem.Template>
    <ControlTemplate>
      <ContentControl Content="{Binding}"></ContentControl>
     </ControlTemplate>
  </ListBoxItem.Template>
</ListBoxItem>
```